# ElasticSearch Query field if has value?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have this documents:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {...},
  "hits": {
    "total": 20584,
    "max_score": 8.143582,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "nyc_visionzero",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "AVwMozs3iTTcr81oIxfl",
        "_score": 8.143582,
        "_source": {
          "date": "02/12/2017",
          "number_of_motorist_injured": 2,
          "contributing_factor_vehicle": "Unsafe Speed",
        }
        ...
```

I want to get all those which field `contributing_factor_vehicle` contains text `unsafe`, if I perform this query:

```
  {
  "query":{
    "query_string": {
      "query": "unsafe"
    }
  }
}
```

It returns all results that contain unsafe, **but I want to limit it to field `contributing_factor_vehicle`**.

## Update mapping

```
{
  "nyc_visionzero": {
    "mappings": {
      "logs": {
        "_all": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "dynamic_templates": [
          {
            "string_fields": {
              "match": "*",
              "match_mapping_type": "string",
              "mapping": {
                "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                    "ignore_above": 256,
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                },
                "omit_norms": true,
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "properties": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "@version": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "borough": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "contributing_factor_vehicle": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "coords": {
            "type": "geo_point"
          },
          "cross_street_name": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "date": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false,
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "host": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false,
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "hour_of_day": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "intersection": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "latitude": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false,
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "location": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false,
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "longitude": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false,
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "message": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false,
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "number_of_cyclist_injured": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "number_of_cyclist_killed": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "number_of_motorist_injured": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "number_of_motorist_killed": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "number_of_pedestrians_injured": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "number_of_pedestrians_killed": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "number_of_persons_injured": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "number_of_persons_killed": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "number_persons_impacted": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "off_street_name": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "on_street_name": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "query": {
            "properties": {
              "match_all": {
                "type": "object"
              }
            }
          },
          "tags": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false,
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "time": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false,
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "unique_key": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false,
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "vehicle_type": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false,
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "zip_code": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false,
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `contributing_factor_vehicle` field is of type `keyword`, which means values will not get `analyzed` and will be stored as they are.

There are two options to resolve this. Either search for exact match using below query:

```
   "query": {
    "term": {
       "contributing_factor_vehicle": {
           "value": "Unsafe Speed"   <--- Exact Term  (check case)
         }
      }
    }
```

Or If you don't want case insensitive search create `contributing_factor_vehicle` as multifield which is by default in `ES 5` Or you create it yourself if your version is < `5.x`

```
POST index
 {
  "mappings": {
    "type": {
     "properties": {
        "contributing_factor_vehicle": {
           "type": "string",
           "fields": {
              "raw": {
                 "type": "string",
                 "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
           }
        } 
       }
      }
     }}
```

And then you can query like this. :

```
 {
  "query":{
      "query_string": {
        "query": "unsafe",
        "default_field" : "contributing_factor_vehicle"

   }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried adding `"default_field": "{contributing_factor_vehicle}"` and `"default_field" : "contributing_factor_vehicle"` and I get  `"hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  } `

Comment: Can you share the mapping.  `GET index/type/_mapping`